# how to arrange crossJoin result with laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I get the result of two tables using cross join. but when I try to show it in the view I get this error

> Call to a member function crossJoin() on array

so how to arrange it in an HTML table? looks like below.

```
barcode | desc | qty | branch1 | branch2 | branch3 | branch4
------------------------------------------------------------
123456  | lenovo| 100  |  null   |  null   |  null   |  null   
252666  | hp    | 100  |  null   |  null   |  null   |  null  
895566  | acer  | 70   |  null   |  null   |  null   |  null  
968411  | apple | 800  |  null   |  null   |  null   |  null
```

here is my code

```php
$receiving = DB::select('select * from branch')
               ->crossJoin('allocation_stocks')->get();
return view('operation.home', ['data' => $receiving]);
```

table allocation_stocks

```
barcode | desc | qty 
----------------------
123456  | lenovo| 100  
252666  | hp    | 100 
895566  | acer  | 70   
968411  | apple | 800
```

table branch

```
brach_name|
-----------
branch1 
branch2 
branch3 
branch4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query. It should work

```php
$receiving = DB::table('branch')
               ->crossJoin('allocation_stocks')
               ->get();
return view('operation.home', ['data' => $receiving]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform a "cross join" use the crossJoin method with the name of the table you wish to cross join to.

Cross joins generate a cartesian product between the first table and the joined table:

```
$receiving = DB::table('branch')
    ->crossJoin('allocation_stocks')
    ->get();
```

See also:

[Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins)

Comment: how to arrange it. while branches are at the header part.

Comment: With the [select()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#selects) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can see the query builder in laravel here.
```

> [Cross Join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

```
$result = DB::table('branch')
               ->crossJoin('allocation_stocks')
               ->get();

return view('operation.home', ['data' => $result]);
```